# Not able to dynamically set the setVisibility() parameter

Tags: java, android, view

I am trying to set the visibility for a button as follows:

```
public Bundle setActivityState(Bundle bundle){
    startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startSensorsBtn);

    startBtn.setVisibility(
            getVisibilityState(bundle, PersistanceConstants.START_BTN_STATE)
    );          

    return bundle;
}

public int getVisibilityState(Bundle bundle, String keyName){
    if (bundle.getInt(keyName) == View.VISIBLE){
        return View.VISIBLE;
    } else if (bundle.getInt(keyName) == View.INVISIBLE){
        return View.INVISIBLE;
    } else if (bundle.getInt(keyName) == View.GONE){
        return View.GONE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Must be one of: View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, View.GONE less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Reports two types of problems:
- Supplying the wrong type of resource identifier. For example, when calling Resources.getString(int id), you should be passing R.string.something, not R.drawable.something.
- Passing the wrong constant to a method which expects one of a specific set of constants. For example, when calling View#setLayoutDirection, the parameter must be android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR or android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL.
```

while calling

```
getVisibilityState(bundle, PersistanceConstants.START_BTN_STATE)
```

I don't know how to get around this. I understand that it's expecting a given set of values but all I know is to pass an `int` to it. What can be done here?

Comment: post your error log ..

Comment: getVisibilityState reach the line `return 0;`? please, post your error log.

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention this. I am getting this during compile time in Android studio.

Comment: Change `return 0` by `return View.VISIBLE`

Comment: I did that. Its still giving the same error.

Comment: @selvin Oops. Completely ignored that part.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you know what you're doing, you can suppress this Android Studio inspection locally with

```
//noinspection ResourceType
```

For example,

```
//noinspection ResourceType
startBtn.setVisibility(bundle.getInt(PersistanceConstants.START_BTN_STATE));
```

Answer (score 18):

A bit late to the party but another solution if you are using this a lot in your code and you have a method returning that int is to define your own Visibility annotation, so something like this:

```
public class MyStuff {

    @IntDef({View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, View.GONE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface Visibility {
    }

    public @Visibility int getVisibility() {
        return View.GONE;
    }
}
```

If you do so then AS won't complain anymore because you are returning a proper int def.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin code:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
@IntDef(View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, View.GONE)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class Visibility
```